# Activate checkbox if I click on the label [Vue.js]

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, label

I was watching this youtube tutorial for making a toggle component.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0hp2NF5OzU&ab_channel=LaurentPerrier

On the 23th second of the video he shows that if you click on the label, the checkbox is activated. I have the same code, but it doesn't work for me. I must click on the checkbox itself in order to activate it. Here is my code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox">this is my label</label>
</div>
```

I see nothing different in my code. Did they change somthing in Vue? I am using version 3.2.40

Answer (score 0):

The [`<label for="x">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/for) + `<input id="x">` behavior is not related to Vue (or to JavaScript, for that matter).

It is [native HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#attr-label-for):

> The `for` attribute may be specified to indicate a form control with which the caption (e.g: the `<label>`) is to be associated. If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value must be the [ID](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-id) of a [labelable element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#category-label) in the same [tree](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree) as the label element. If the attribute is specified and there is an element in the tree whose ID is equal to the value of the `for` attribute, and the first such element in [tree order](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-tree-order) is a labelable element, then that element is the label element's [labeled control](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#labeled-control).

Given the above definition, most likely, there is another element with `id="checkbox"` placed in DOM before the `<input>` which should be controlled by the current label.

---

If the above explanation doesn't help pinpoint the source of the unexpected behavior, please create a *runnable* [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) making sure it reproduces the bug.
The code currently posted is not sufficient, for two reasons:

- it is not *runnable*
- even if someone would create a runnable snippet from the code posted in the question, it would not reproduce the described behavior